# Should I re-pot this orchid?

Tags: orchids

I am wondering if this orchid has outgrown it's pot?

If it is, should I wait until spring, or should I re-pot it right away. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would re-pot it if it were me. I've grown these Phaelenopsis orchids for years, and they're pretty forgiving. I've not noticed them caring much about the seasons - it's going into winter here and a couple of mine are sending up new flower spikes, so I don't think it matters if you wait for spring. If it were sending up a spike I'd probably wait.